# Uno Platform App tracking prompt does not appear in IOS 15

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uno-platform

I am updating my Uno based app and in testing-the app tracking prompt no longer appears.  I had implemented this and it works correctly in iOS 14.  In iOS 14 I am able to go into the privacy settings and see that the user has selected if they want to be tracked or not.  I dont see any of this in iOS 15.  In my research, it appears that I need to override the onActivated method in appDelegate and put the prompt code in there.  I dont have an appDelegate class in my project so I tried adding one in app.iOS but it could not find the formsApplicationdelegate the example had. Also- when I look in settings in iOS it does not show the app as having a tracking/no tracking choice.  I am guessing this will show once I get the prompt to show?  I did verify the setting is in my info.plist.  What is the best way to do this?

Here is my current implementation:

info.plist:

```
<key>NSUserTrackingUsageDescription</key>
    <string>The App would like to access the identifier for analytics purposes</string>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
#if __IOS__
using AppTrackingTransparency;
#endif

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
 public MainPage()
 {
#if __IOS__
               try
               {
               ATTrackingManager.RequestTrackingAuthorization((status) => {
                     if (status == ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
                        {
                          //do something
                
                        }
                  else if (status == ATTrackingManagerAuthorizationStatus.Denied)
                     {
                        //do something
                     }
                 });
               }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       //do something
    }
#endif
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my research, it appears that I need to override the onActivated method in appDelegate and put the prompt code in there. I dont have an appDelegate class in my project (...)

The `App` class (in App.xaml.cs) inherits from `Windows.UI.Xaml.Application` which in turn inherits from `UIApplicationDelegate`.

This means you should be able to do the following in App.xaml.cs.

```cs
#if __IOS__
    public override void OnActivated(UIKit.UIApplication application)
    {
        // Your code.
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much- this worked.  the only tweak I had to make was to remove the base.OnActivated(application)- it threw an exception saying it should not be called here.  I appreciated your explanation as that will help int he future.  Thank you again.

Comment: Great! I've edited the code sample to remove the `base.OnActivated(application)` line.